# Word for wise person who can see the big picture when others cannot

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Bonus if this word talks about this person using this knowledge to guide others. But word without guidance in meaning can still be used in my sentence as an adjective.

> The professor was ——- and used that to guide his students towards the right direction.

Comment: Nothing wrong with "the professor could see the big picture". Also, the "towards" really wants to be an "in".

Comment: The words "and used that" somewhat complicate the provision of an answer - some solutions sound a bit awkward with this construction.

Comment: "Wise" is a very good word.

Comment: really, in "US Business talk" the exact phrased used is "a big picture person".

Comment: Sagacious would seem the obvious choice.

Answer (score 16):

The professor was ***[visionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/visionary)***

> with the ability to imagine how a country, society, industry, etc. will develop in the future.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I'm not sure but I personally distinguish between "being able to envision a future" and "seeing the big picture [of a situation]", i.e. being able to spot patterns, being able to see things from a different perspective. I would for example say that Elon Musk is a visionary, but not far-sighted in that other sense. Is there such a distinction? To me, visionary is too close to dreamer/romancer.

Answer (score 9):

In British English the word is **far-sighted**.

> far-sighted adjective UK ​  /ˌfɑːˈsaɪ.tɪd/ US ​  /ˌfɑːrˈsaɪ.t̬ɪd/
>
> far-sighted adjective (WISE) ​
>
> uk having good judgment about what will
> be needed in the future and making wise decisions based on this:
>
> Buying those shares was a very far-sighted move - they must be worth
> ten times their original value now.
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/far-sighted

However I believe that farsighted in American English may have a different meaning.

EDIT

Based on discussion in the comments below and thanks to the link provided by Chappo, I quote Merriam-Webster. However I also note that Timbo would assume hyperopia by default. I defer to native speakers of AmE in their knowledge of their own version of English.

> farsighted adjective far·​sight·​ed | \ˈfär-ˌsī-təd  \ Definition of
> farsighted  1a : seeing or able to see to a great distance b : having
> or showing foresight or good judgment : SAGACIOUS 2 : affected with
> hyperopia
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farsighted

Comment: Why do you believe AmE is different? Did you check [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farsighted)? The only difference is MW doesn't hyphenate it. You might like to [edit] your answer re AmE, as on this point it's currently misleading for future readers. Happy to upvote if edited, as "farsighted" was the first word that I thought of too :-)

Comment: @Chappo `2: affected with hyperopia`. I guess this different meaning was meant.

Comment: @OleksandrKaraberov not hyperopic; any native English speaker will instinctively choose the intended meaning. English abounds in metaphoric usages. If he was *luminary*, we don't assume he's "a body that gives light". If he was *gifted*, it wouldn't mean he'd been donated. In fact, the play on double meanings is an intrinsic element of much of our verbal humour.

Comment: @Chappo Thanks for a nice insight. Valid point. Not being a native speaker I miss sometimes this subtle ability to first recognise a metaphorical rather than literal meaning. But as for your other examples I'm not that slow-witted :)

Comment: @Chappo Native AmE speaker here and I would absolutely assume hyperopia or at least sense 1a from MW, a non-metaphorical reference to the sense of sight. Without further context, I would assume an implication that the students were all nearsighted or blind.

Comment: Fascinating! Even though MW lists the optical condition as the *secondary* meaning! It amazes me there isn’t greater misunderstanding when AmE and BritE talk to each other. Canadians must have so much fun with these differences:-)

Comment: @OleksandrKaraberov Even native/fluent speakers sometimes have to ask “do you mean [meaning 1] or [meaning 2]?” Hence the idiomatic question “funny unusual or funny haha?” when someone says “That’s funny” without adequate context.

Comment: "The professor was far-sighted and used that to guide his students" - as a native AmE speaker I would definitely trip over this, assuming hyperopia, and then have to go back and revise my understanding to be more metaphorical so the sentence made sense. Interestingly, the opposite wouldn't be a problem - if you describe a person or decision as *nearsighted* I'll know what you mean right away, though *short-sighted* is more common. But in this situation, the closest I could come to the intended meaning would be to say that the professor **had great foresight**.

Answer (score 5):

You can say that the professor was ‘luminary’ - a shining light that inspired or guided others, or illuminated their path.

Definition: ‘a person who inspires or influences others, especially one prominent in a particular sphere.
"one of the luminaries of child psychiatry"
synonyms:   leading light, guiding light, inspiration, role model, hero, heroine, leader, expert, master; More’

Answer (score 4):

You can say the professor was [far-seeing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/far-seeing):

> Having shrewd judgement and an ability to predict and plan for future eventualities.

This word is quite simple and yet has a connotation of acumen and shrewdness.

Comment: *Far-**sighted*** sounds better to me.

Answer (score 3):

I went with:

> [Sage:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sage) ​
>
> **Wise, especially as a result of *great experience*.**

Which can be used as noun or adjective.

"The professor was sage, and used that attribute to guide his students towards the right direction."

Alternatively:

"The professor was *a* sage, and guided his students in the right direction."

Answer (score 3):

"See the big picture" is itself a little ambiguous.

If you're thinking of seeing how all the parts fit together **at a given point in time**, consider *astute*, *perceptive*, *observant*, or *insightful*:

**astute** (adj.) having or showing shrewdness and an ability to notice and understand things clearly

**perceptive** (adj.) characterized by sympathetic understanding or insight

**observant** (adj.) Keep, perceptive

**insightful** (adj.) exhibiting or characterized by the power or act of seeing into a situation

However, the student-teacher example makes me thing that you may be looking for an adjective that means the teacher can see how a situation may play out **over time**.

In that case, consider *perspicacious*, *far-sighted*, or even plain-old *wise*:

**perspicacious** (adj.) of acute mental vision or discernment

**far-sighted** (adj.) having or showing foresight or good judgment : SAGACIOUS

**wise** (adj.) characterized by wisdom : marked by deep understanding, keen discernment, and a capacity for sound judgment.

(All definitions are from Merriam-Webster online: https://www.merriam-webster.com/)

Answer (score 1):

To approximate the ability to see the big picture in a single word, we can perhaps use ***clear-sighted***.

> The professor was ***clear-sighted*** and used that to guide his
>   students towards the right direction.

ODO:

> **[clear-sighted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/clear-sighted)** *ADJECTIVE*
>   Thinking clearly and sensibly; perspicacious and discerning.
>
> ‘a clear-sighted sense of what is possible and appropriate’
>
> ‘What is needed is a clear-sighted reappraisal of where we stand,
>   before we can plot a path forwards.’
>
> **[perspicacious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perspicacious)** *ADJECTIVE*
>   Having a ready insight into and understanding of things.
>
> ‘If only our parents could have been perspicacious enough to see our
>   talent and force us into showbiz.’
>
> **[discerning](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discerning)** *ADJECTIVE*
>   Having or showing good judgement.
>
> ‘Physicians are by inclination and training discerning men, wise in
>   human relations and keen in judgement.’

Answer (score 0):

Lofty, or Sublime.  Expansive is close, with a strongly benevolent meaning.  Something along those lines, lot's on this page here... -->  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/lofty

Comment: I don't think a professor would like to be called "lofty" as this suggests arrogance, and "sublime" is an excessive compliment and inappropriate to the context here.

Comment: He didn't ask what compliment would be well accepted by a professor, that's a different stackexchange.

Comment: Quite right. Nonetheless "lofty" is a poor answer, and "sublime" is simply wrong for "a wise person". That's just my opinion, of course, but there's a possibility others might agree with me. You might therefore consider editing your answer to provide evidence to support why you think each of your two words is correct - e.g. quoting from a dictionary. For further guidance, see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single adjective, but "The professor didn't lose the forest in the trees" could be a useful idiom.

Answer (score 0):

I propose **Sagacious**:

> of keen and farsighted penetration and judgment : DISCERNING

*sagacious judge of character*

> caused by or indicating acute discernment

*sagacious purchase of stock*

[Merriam- Webster]